# Find the natural numbers with the property that the product of their divisors is equal to $10^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Find the natural numbers N other than 0 with the property that the product of all of the divisors of N is equal to $10^a$ where a is the number of the divisors of N.

This is my approach:

Let N be a natural number with prime factorization $ N = p_1^{a_1} \cdot p_2^{a_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k^{a_k} $, where $ ( p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k ) $are distinct prime numbers and $( a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k )$ are positive integers.

The number of divisors of  N is given by $( (a_1 + 1) \cdot (a_2 + 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (a_k + 1) ).$

Now, we want the product of the divisors to be equal to ( 10^a ), where ( a ) is the number of divisors. This leads to the equation:

$[ (a_1 + 1) \cdot (a_2 + 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (a_k + 1) = 10^a ]$

For this equation to hold, we can consider two cases:

1. If $ ( a_k \geq 3 )$ for any $( k )$, then the right side of the equation has a prime factor of 5, but the left side does not. This is a contradiction.
2. If $( a_k \leq 2 )$ for all $( k )$, then the right side of the equation is a power of 10, and the left side must also be a power of 10. This implies that each $( a_i + 1 )$ is a power of 2 and 5.

By analyzing the possible combinations, we find that the only natural numbers satisfying the given property are 120 and 100.

Is it correct? I'm not sure about the conclusion, I think there could be more numbers to satisfy the property.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: Tip: Don't write `\(`, write `(` when in math mode.

Comment: @BillDubuque alright, I'm sorry if it seemed like I'm using this website as a "proof checking machine".

Comment: The product of the divisors of $24$ is $24^4\neq 10^a$

Comment: $24$ doesn't satisfy the property. The divisors of $24$ are $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$ so their product is $1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times 6\times 8\times 12\times 24 = 331776$ whereas the quantity $10^a = 10^8=100000000$

Comment: You're right, then the only numbers who satisfy the property should be powers of 10?

Comment: It should be obvious if $k$ is a divisor of $N$ then $k$ is one of the components that constructs the product of the divisors and has to be a divisor of the product as well.  So $N$ can't have any divisors that are not also divisors of $10^a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the product of divisors of a number are given by $n^\frac{\sigma_0(n)}{2}$ where $\sigma_0(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

So, $10^{2a} =N^a$, which gives $N=100$.

In order to see this, you can note that multiplying two of the divisors of $n$ yield $n$, and you just have to count how many time that happens.

You just equated the number of divisors of $n$ to $10^a$, which obviously isn't correct.

Comment: The notation $\sigma(n)$ is traditionally used to denote the **sum** of the divisors of $n$.

Comment: Yes indeed. Shall change that to $\sigma_0$.

Answer (score 0):

For any number (eg 20)
$$
\text{Factors: } 1,2,4,5,10,20
\\
\text{Product: }(1*20)(2*10)(4*5)=20^3
$$

So generally speaking $$\text{Product}=N^{\frac{no. of factors}{2}}$$